# PyMongo : Array filtered positional operator update gives me error

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to run a python code to update a collection with arrays. The below statement give error wtih pymongo . Please guide

```
db.students.update({}, {'$set': {"grades.$[element]": 100}}, {'multi': true, 'arrayFilters': [{"element": { '$gte': 100}}]} )

tried : multi=True tried : multi:True
```

I am getting the below error :
common.validate_boolean("upsert", upsert)
  File "F:\Program Files\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\pymongo\common.py", line 159, in validate_boolean
    raise TypeError("%s must be True or False" % (option,))

```
TypeError: upsert must be True or False
```

Answer (score 0):

Pymongo's syntax is a tad different than Mongo's syntax, you should write it like this:

```
db.students.update({}, {'$set': {"grades.$[element]": 100}}, multi=True, array_filters=[{"element": {'$gte': 100}}])
```

Also [update](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) is deprecated, and in your case you should use [update_many](https://kite.com/python/docs/pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many) instead.

```
db.students.update_many({}, {'$set': {"grades.$[element]": 100}}, array_filters=[{"element": {'$gte': 100}}])
```

Comment: Now i get different error  - write_concern = WriteConcern(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arrayFilters'

Comment: yes.. both queries gave same error , thanks for your guidance

Comment: the argument name is `array_filters`, not `arrayFilters`.